# Artin exercise 2.98: Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: solution-verification, chinese-remainder-theorem

This is exercise 2.98 in Artin's algebra textbook.

> Use Proposition (2.6) to prove the Chinese Remainder Theorem: Let $m,n,a,b$ be integers, and assume the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$ is $1$. Then there is an integer $x$ such that $x \equiv a \text{ (modulo $m$)}$ and $x \equiv b \text{ (modulo $n$)}$.

Proposition 2.6 states the following:

> Let $a,b$ be integers, not both zero, and let $d$ be the positive integer which generates the subgroup $a\mathbb{Z} + b\mathbb{Z}$. Then

> (a) $d$ can be written in the form $d = ar + bs$ for some integers $r$ and $s$.

> (b) $d$ divides $a$ and $b$.

> (c). If an integer $d$ divides $a$ and $b$, it also divides $d$.

Below is my attempt. I'm hoping someone can check this over.

> By Proposition (2.6), since $(m,n) = 1$, there exist integers $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $sm + tn = 1$. Multiplying by $b-a$, we get
> \begin{align*}
> s(b-a)m + t(b-a)n = b - a.
> \end{align*}
> Let $y = s(b-a)m + a$. So we have $y + t(b-a)n = b$. Then $y - b = t(b-a)n$, so $y \equiv b \text{ (mod $n$)}$. Furthermore, subtracting $a$ from both sides and rearranging, we have
> \begin{align*}
> y - a = -t(b-a)n + (b - a) = -t(b-a)n + s(b-a)m + t(b-a)n = s(b-a)m,
> \end{align*}
> so $y \equiv a \text{ (mod $m$)}$, giving a solution to this system of congruences.

Comment: If you are going to use a proposition place cite what the proposition *says* in the body of your text.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added its statement.

Comment: It looks good. But you can get the last congruence directly from the definition of $y$ a lot easier than the way you did it. (That way also works, so you aren't wrong. You are just proving something you already knew.)

Comment: In fact, I would suggest rearranging your first centered equation as $$s(b-a)m + a = b - t(b-a)n$$then defining $y$ as the common value. Both modular equations follow more simply then.